# java URLConnection - how to read data from URLs containing uppercase?

Tags: java, url, uri

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html has an example with:

```
URL oracle = new URL("http://www.oracle.com/");
```

that works fine, but if the URL has uppercase, like https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/file_example_PPT_250kB.ppt

then get error about URL not exists (and there is https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/file_example_ppt_250kb.ppt in the stack trace)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

URL/filename.fileformate in this filename is case sensitive you have to manage tolowercase  when you create it

Comment: but https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/file_example_ppt_250kb.ppt is not a valid URL (even in browser)

Comment: its valid only page not found

Comment: not found because that URL with lower does not exist

Answer (score 1):

you are getting a resource in this URL and resources are case sensitive. So file_example_PPT_250kB.ppt and file_example_ppt_250kb.ppt are two different resources for a web server.

For more info read

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/90339/why-are-urls-case-sensitive

Comment: how to download this URL via java?

Comment: Well you can't download the resource if it is not available with the exact same name. if you  want to make a get call, there are plenty of example available. https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-send-http-request-getpost-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

closing, some upstream code is changing the casing